# mistake in passport no while booking slot for visa @vfs .how to rectify

Tags: visas, schengen, vfs-global

while booking an  appointment  for visa to Italy, I made a mistake in typing my Passport No. Instead of R***** , I might have typed T*****. Except this mistake, all are informations are correct. How to rectify this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to cancel the appointment and make a new one with the correct passport number.

According to [vfsglobal](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/bgd/en/deu/faq) official FAQ:

> **I made a mistake while booking an appointment or I entered the wrong passport number while booking an appointment. What should I do?** 
> All data submitted while booking an appointment must be correct, otherwise you will not be allowed to enter VFS Global premises . If you made a mistake while booking an appointment, please cancel it through the appointment system. You can book an appointment with the correct information right after.